# Migrating blogs data from Drupal 7, Combine two select statement and create output table

Tags: mysql, database, drupal-7

I am working on migration a portal from drupal 7 into new stack. I want to retrieve and combine data from node table and url_alias to have blogs and slugs in the same table.

I am able to fetch blog data into one statement and fetch slugs (using replace function and case) with second statement. How can I combine those two statements and insert results into new table?

statement 1:

```
Select t1.nid, 
       t1.vid, 
       t1.title, 
       t2.body_value as body 
from `node` as t1 
left join `field_revision_body` as t2 ON t1.vid = t2.revision_id
where t1.type = 'blog';
```

which gives me an output like:

```
|nid|vid|title|body|
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN url_alias.alias LIKE "%news/%" THEN REPLACE(url_alias.alias, "news/", "") end as slug, 
       case when url_alias.source LIKE "%node/%" THEN 
REPLACE(url_alias.source, "node/", "") end as nodeId 
from url_alias 
where url_alias.alias LIKE "news/%" and url_alias.source like "%node/%";
```

which gives me an output like:

```
|slug|nodeId|
```

after removing "node/" from url_alias.source I have now nodeId which is a key for nid or vid. I would like to create an output table which will combine two outputs into one new table like:

|nid|vid|title|body|slug|

How can I join them ?

Comment: You want the columns returned by both queries insert into a new table ? If so you can use insert into select

Comment: insert into I know but I don't know how to join two statements into one query, I am not very good with SQL, at least yet :)

Answer (score 0):

One method would be using `UNION`.

You can try something like:

```
    INSERT INTO your_table_name (   nid 
                               ,vid 
                               ,title 
                               ,body 
                               ,slug 
                               ,nodeId
                               
SELECT       a.nid 
            ,a.vid 
            ,a.title 
            ,a.body 
            ,a.slug 
            ,a.nodeId
            
            
FROM (   
        SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT t1.nid, 
                    t1.vid, 
                    t1.title, 
                    t2.body_value as body,
                    null as slug,
                    null as nodeId,
             FROM `node` as t1 
             LEFT JOIN  `field_revision_body` as t2 ON t1.vid = t2.revision_id
             WHERE t1.type = 'blog' 
           ) 
        UNION
    
           (
              SELECT null as a.nid, 
               null as vid, 
               null as title, 
               null as body 
               CASE WHEN url_alias.alias LIKE "%news/%" THEN REPLACE(url_alias.alias, "news/", "") end as slug, 
               CASE WHEN url_alias.source LIKE "%node/%" THEN  REPLACE(url_alias.source, "node/", "") end as nodeId 
            FROM url_alias 
            WHERE url_alias.alias LIKE "news/%" AND url_alias.source LIKE "%node/%"
            )   
            
                      ) as a;
```

Comment: Unrecognized keyword near as... (the last line)

Comment: I think the problem is with lines NULL as "column"

Comment: @MichalMajeran try now and let me know